# Dynamic array that populates via looped inputbox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to get a user to input weight based on the number of pallets.  The `NumberPallets` is set via an input box somewhere else in the code.

NumberPallets is 3.  I want this to loop 3 times and ask for the weights of each pallet and store that into PalletWeights(p) so it would look like this:

```
PalletWeight(1) = 200
PalletWeight(2) = 100
PalletWeight(3) = 300

TotalPalletWeight = 600
```

Right now it is giving me a subscript error and I believe it's because I'm not properly doing the array.  I've Googled tried to use PalletWeight(Ubound(PalletWeight)) but that does not work either.  Other Google Search yields virtually no results for taking InputBox data individually and not in a comma separated list.

What do I need to change to make this function?

```
ReDim PalletWeights(1 to NumberPallets) 'Added based on an answer on this question

Dim PalletWeights() As String 'Array of pallet weights
Dim p As Integer
p = 1
Do While p <= NumberPallets

    PalletWeights(p) = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the weight of pallet number " & p & "?", Type:=1)
    p = p + 1
Loop

TotalPalletWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(PalletWeights)
```

**NEW Full working code:**

```
'Pallet Weights
Dim PalletWeights() 'Array of pallet weights
Dim p As Integer
p = 1

ReDim PalletWeights(1 To NumberPallets)

Do While p <= NumberPallets

     'Total Weight
      PalletWeights(p) = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the weight of pallet number " & p & "?", Type:=1)
      TotalWeight = TotalWeight + PalletWeights(p)
      p = p + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a Dynamic Array.  It is not sized until you explicitly size it.

Try adding before the Do loop

```
ReDim PalletWeights(1 to NumberPallets)
```

Comment: This worked but the sum doesn't work.  I output the values of the array as they go in and the values are there.  I've also tried to do TotalWeight=TotalWeight+PalletWeights(p) but it doesn't do the math.  It just takes 100 and 200 and makes TotalWeight 100200.

Comment: I got it.  I took out "as string" on the array and just left it as "Dim PalletWeights()" and that fixed the sum part.  I just sum it in the loop as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add ReDim expression after loop. See following.

```
Dim PalletWeights() As String 'Array of pallet weights
Dim p As Integer
p = 1
Do While p <= NumberPallets

 PalletWeights(p) = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the weight of         pallet number " & p & "?", Type:=1)
 p = p + 1
Loop

ReDim PalletWeights(p)

TotalPalletWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(PalletWeights)
```

Comment: See below answer, it is tested.

Comment: Does not work for me.  I posted the working code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to assign array size with ReDim, then you can store data in array. As you are summing data, that's why you need to declare array as integer not string.

```
    Public Sub ArraySum()
            Dim PalletWeights() As Integer 'Array of pallet weights
            Dim p, TotalPalletWeight As Integer
            ReDim PalletWeights(5)
            p = 1
            Do While p <= 5
            PalletWeights(p) = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the weight of         pallet number " & p & "?", Type:=1)
             p = p + 1
            Loop
            TotalPalletWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(PalletWeights)
            MsgBox TotalPalletWeight
    End Sub
```